# SetTimeout in TextInput component of React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am try to making a `SearchBar` component in my new android application.

I am new in React-Native so i did this style for pass `text` to a local function that i called it `_changeInput()`. Pass mission was correct but when i try to add a `setTimeout`, my code was broken and my `setTimeOut` dose not work.

**The Goal :** i want to pass `TextInput` value to `_changeInput()` after 1 second.

See the below code and help me if you can :

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isLoading : false
    }
    lastTimeout = setTimeout; 
}

_changeInput(text) {
    Alert.alert('OoopS', text )
}

render() {
    return(
        ...

                <TextInput 
                    numberOfLines={1}
                    returnKeyType="search"

                    onChangeText={ (text) => {
                        clearTimeout(this.lastTimeout);
                        this.lastTimeout = setTimeout(() => {this._changeInput(text)} ,1000)
                    } }

                />
...
```

Comment: but why in textInput ? use function to handle change event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :-/

`Check that your device's time matches that of your computer! This happened to me and took an unfortunately long while to debug haha`

[see more](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9030)

So i changed time to 5000 milisecond and it's work fine